# How data in fetched from DocumentDB in a Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, azure-cosmosdb

I wonder to know how I can control the way data is fetched into mappers from DocumentDB? I mean how many JSON docs are given to a mapper etc?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the documents are fetched in 700 documents batches which is done as a good average.
The maximum you can set is 1000 documents, may I ask why would you like to change it ?

You currently can't change it as a config.
if you build the connector yourself, if you build it yourself, you can change it here 
[github link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop/blob/master/src/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/hadoop/DocumentDBInputSplit.java#L41)

If you have a good use case for it, you can open an issue on github to ask for ability to change it using config.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to change it I was just wondering to know how many docs are fetched. May I asked how come 700 is (sort of) optimal number of fetching? What other parameters I have control over?

Comment: 700 was made as kind of conservative number to avoid a lot of throttling taking into account the document sizes, but big enough that it fetches big page at a time for performance.

Comment: you can look here for all the configurations that you can modify
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-hadoop 
look at hive load and save examples for all the conf you can change.

Comment: let me know if you have any questions about any of these configs